# Cannot make a basic HTTP auth with node request module

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, mocha.js, basic-authentication

I am testing my app with mocha and I would like to test a HTTP response header code depending on the credentials that I sent to it with a basic HTTP authentication.

In the client side, I made the AJAX call to the server like this:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
       xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " +btoa("username:password") );
     },
     success:function(rsp){
          // do whatever I need;
     }
  });
```

And it works perfectly. It the credentials are wrong, then the website will respond wit a **302**

In my test file (*mocha*), I try to sent the same request but for some reason it does not work.

Here is the different way I tried:

```
it('should return 302 because wrong credentials', function(done){
 var auth = "Basic " +new Buffer("username:password").toString('base64');
  var options = {
      url: url,
      headers: {
      "Authorization": auth
      }
   };

   request.get(options, function(err, res, body){
      console.log(res.statusCode);
      assert.equal(302, res.statusCode);
     done();
   });
});

-----------------------

it('should return 302 because wrong credentials', function(done){
    request.get(url,
    {
      'auth': {
         'username':'username', 
         'password':'password'
       }
    }, 
    function(err, res, body) {
       assert.equal(302, res.statusCode);
       done();
    });
 });
```

But, in anyway, I get a HTTP **200** response code.

So why? And how should I handle it?

Ps: For those who are very cautious, the client is not to be used publicly and thus I allow myself to put credentials in it.

**EDIT:** To be more precise, you will find below the server code (NodeJS) which handle the request

```
function checkAuth(req, result, next){

  var header = req.headers['authorization'];

  // Ignore the preflight OPTION call
  if(header != undefined){
    var tmp = header.split(/\s+/).pop();
    var credentials = new Buffer(tmp, 'base64').toString();
    var parts = credentials.split(/:/);
    var username = parts[0];
    var password = parts[1];

    bcrypt.compare(username, config.get.username, function(err, res){
      if(res){
        bcrypt.compare(password, config.get.password, function(err, res){
          if(res){
            next();
          } else {
            return result.redirect('/');
          }
        });
      } else {
        return result.redirect('/');
      }
    });
  } else {
    return result.redirect('/');
  }

}

app.get('/server', checkAuth, getData.getMessages);
```

And the method `getData.getMessage()` return the following:

```
return result.status(200).json(res);
```

Comment: Maybe it's a server problem, could  you tell us which HTTP server you are using and if possible the code that handles the auth request.

Comment: @MinusFour: for sure, thanks for the help :)

Comment: It isn't a server error: `Request is designed to be the simplest way possible to make http calls. It supports HTTPS and follows redirects by default.`

Comment: That was my thought. So where this 200 can cone from??

Comment: From your `/` redirect, request will follow that (by doing a new request to `/`) and will get you a normal `200` response code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request` automatically follows redirects so you'll need to disable `followRedirect` to read `3xx` responses.

```
var options = {
      url: url,
      followRedirect: false, 
      headers: {
      "Authorization": auth
      }
   };
```

Comment: Hell yeah. Well, almost. 
You should correct your answer, it is not `followRequest` but `followRedirect`. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

For HTTP Basic authentication you can also use [http-auth](https://github.com/http-auth/http-auth) module.

```
// Authentication module.
var auth = require('http-auth');
var basic = auth.basic({
    realm: "Simon Area.",
    file: __dirname + "/../data/users.htpasswd" // gevorg:gpass, Sarah:testpass ...
});

// Creating new HTTP server.
http.createServer(basic, function(req, res) {
    res.end("Welcome to private area - " + req.user + "!");
}).listen(1337);
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice mate!